# square listCustomers call does not include custom fields in Response customer object

Tags: rest, square, square-connect

I'm trying to come up to speed on the Square API.   I have been able to successfully create a post call to CreateCustomer() and a get call to ListCustomers(). In both cases, the customer objects come through fine but the custom fields I have added to extend the customer object are not present.  When I add, view and edit Customers using the Square Dashboard they show up as expected.  They are also present if I export Customers from the Dashboard.

Is there a way to get the custom fields to be included in Square's Rest API calls?

Answer (score 0):

At this time Square's APIs will not return custom fields.